# Bash script 'mv -f' embedded in Perl file

Tags: bash, perl

Attempting to move directory which contains sub-directory to the /opt using perl. Just perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warning

system(

'echo "Copy the application directory here and paste it here"

read apple

mv -f $apple /opt

');
```

This returns

```
mv: cannot stat "'/root/dump'": No such file or directory
```

My input for `read apple` is `/root/dump` which is a directory. When I did it directly from terminal it worked but then by perl file it doesn't. Could you be descriptive as possible, as I'm not that familiar with bash script please? Thank you in Advance.

Update:

I tried the bash file I wrote

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Copy the application directory here and paste it here"

read apple

mv -f $apple /opt
```

This also returns the same result as perl.

Comment: There's not much point in writing a Perl program that just shells out to execute bash commands. Why no write a shell script instead? It doesn't work as it is because `system` will accept only one shell command.

Comment: This is just a part that is integrated with perl codes. Do you think I should write them separately? Perl and Bash

Comment: @Borodin I rewrote the code in a bash file but the result is exactly the same one. I don't understand what makes it returns "No such file or directory" even though it exists.

Comment: *"Do you think I should write them separately?"*  No, I think you should write it all in Perl.

Comment: It should also complain about being unable to find `warning.pm` in `@INC`.

Comment: Do you get `mv: cannot stat "'/root/dump'": No such file or directory` or `mv: cannot stat '"/root/dump"': No such file or directory`? Watch the quotes.

Comment: Do not turn on warnings in the shebang line. Some modules do dangerous stuff and turn off warnings, `no warnings;` But if warnings are turned on in the shebang, then they cannot be turned off; warnings about hings the module must do will be shown.

Answer (score 3):

If it literally says `"'/root/dump'"` that means you have added some literal [quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) in addition to the syntactic ones. Make sure to quote `$apple` in your Bash script and *not* quote the stuff you give to `read`.

Comment: echo "Copy the application here and paste it here"

read apple

mv -f $apple /opt                                                                                      is this correct form?

Comment: @Seho Sorry, but what am I supposed to do with that comment? Certainly as a single line that won't do what you expect. Please update your question if you've tried something else.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use *just perl*, instead of `system()`ing out to a shell, use  `dirmove()` from [File::Copy::Recursive](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive) to move the directory tree.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, you just want to move a directory recoursively to `/opt`. This script does just that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

print "Copy the application directory here and paste it here: ";
chomp (my $apple = <STDIN>);
`mv -f $apple /opt`;
```

> using perl. Just perl.

I don't understand that. You are using system commands in your code provided above. If you want to use just perl use `dirmove() from File::Copy::Recursive` as Shawn mentioned already. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Seho if the answer did not help you could you clarify your question? What do you want to achieve?